# How to convert data into Matrix format

Tags: r

I have imported raw data (10000 rows and 392 columns) into R by read.csv. I am wondering how I can convert that into Matrix format. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 8):

Your question will probably be migrated to StackOverflow.  However, the answer is relatively simple and I will provide it.  read.csv produces a data.frame as a result.  If all of your values are the same basic element (i.e. variable) type, i.e. numeric, character, etc.  Then you can represent them in the Matrix data-structure.  You can do so with the "as.matrix" function.

e.g.

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,3))    
mymatrix <- as.matrix(mydataframe)
```

Answer (score 6):

If the data were read by `read.csv` but actually are consistent with `matrix`, then use `scan` in the first place, maybe using `skip=1` to skip a header line.

```
m = matrix(scan("file.csv", what=numeric(), skip=1), nrow=392)
```

scan is disconcerting fast compared to read.csv for data with simple structure.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `as.matrix()` is `data.matrix()`, which has the benefit of preserving the numeric (coded) information of factor variables when converting to a matrix. Consider:

```
d <- data.frame(1:10, letters[1:10])
as.matrix(d)
data.matrix(d)

> as.matrix(d)
      X1.10 letters.1.10.
 [1,] " 1"  "a"          
 [2,] " 2"  "b"          
 [3,] " 3"  "c"          
 [4,] " 4"  "d"          
 [5,] " 5"  "e"          
 [6,] " 6"  "f"          
 [7,] " 7"  "g"          
 [8,] " 8"  "h"          
 [9,] " 9"  "i"          
[10,] "10"  "j"          
> data.matrix(d)
      X1.10 letters.1.10.
 [1,]     1             1
 [2,]     2             2
 [3,]     3             3
 [4,]     4             4
 [5,]     5             5
 [6,]     6             6
 [7,]     7             7
 [8,]     8             8
 [9,]     9             9
[10,]    10            10
```

Notice how the presence of a factor with text labels renders the entire matrix cast by `as.matrix()` as a character matrix whereas `data.matrix()` preserves the numeric nature of the data by replacing the factor labels with their internal numeric code.