# convert csv file to matrix in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I have a csv file

```
 User_name    M_User    Total
    user 1    user 2     7
    user 1    user 3     19
    user 1    user 7     5
    user 3    user 2     1
    user 2    user 7     1
```

and I want to convert it in matrix form

```
            user 1  user 2  user 3  user 7
user 1        0        7     19       5
user 3        0        1      0       0
user 2        0        0      0       1
user 7        0        0      0       0
```

what I;m doing right now is something like this

```
require(reshape2)
m <- as.matrix(dcast(df, USER_NAME ~ M_USER, value.var = "TOTAL", fill=0))[,1:4]
```

but the answer I get is

```
 USER_NAME   user 2 user 3 user 7
[1,] "user 1"  "7"    "19"   "5"   
[2,] "user 2"  "0"    " 0"   "1"   
[3,] "user 3"  "1"    " 0"   "0"
```

How can I modify the code so that I get this matrix

```
            user 1 user 2 user 3  user 7
user 1        0        7     19       5
user 3        0        1      0       0
user 2        0        0      0       1
user 7        0        0      0       0
```

Comment: Just do `xtabs(Total ~User_name + M_User, df)`

Comment: Politely, your output there is what a matrix should look like (as you can see here [1]: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-matrices-and-matrix-computations-in-r/). Could you maybe tell us more about your goals for the output so we might better provide some guidance? for example, is there a reason you need it to be a matrix? what are you actually doing with the output?

Comment: You can read the csv file as a matrix using `read.csv`. Read this [package documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-May/237835.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert data into Matrix format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593402/how-to-convert-data-into-matrix-format)

Comment: @Masoud The question here is not only about the class of the object, it's about crosstabulating. In the linked question it is only about the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Total ~User_name + M_User, df, drop = FALSE)
#         M_User
#User_name user 1 user 2 user 3 user 7
#  user 1      0      7     19      5
#  user 2      0      0      0      1
#  user 3      0      1      0      0
#  user 7      0      0      0      0
```

---

Also, there is `acast` from `reshape2` which gives a `matrix` output

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df, User_name ~ M_User, value.var = "Total", fill=0, drop = FALSE)
#       user 1 user 2 user 3 user 7
#user 1      0      7     19      5
#user 2      0      0      0      1
#user 3      0      1      0      0
#user 7      0      0      0      0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(User_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("user 1", 
"user 2", "user 3", "user 7"), class = "factor"), M_User = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("user 1", "user 2", "user 3", "user 7"
), class = "factor"), Total = c(7L, 19L, 5L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("User_name", 
"M_User", "Total"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This works when I enter the data like you did however when I read from the csv file the output is the same as mentioned in my original post :/

Comment: 'df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/test.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE )' isn't this the right way to read it?

Comment: @melissa  Can you please check the `str(df)`

Comment: ok str(df) shows your data has 4 levels as for my csv file it shows only 3 levels :/

Comment: @melissa  Does it show only a single column?  IN that case, you have a problem with the `sep`

Comment: @melissa I think  based on your output, it is working correctly except that you had 3 rows in the output.  It is only because your columns may not have the same levels. Try `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], factor, levels = c("user 1", "user 2", "user 3", "user 7"))`  Also, wrapping with `as.matrix` on a `data.frame` with a character column will result in converting the class to character as matrix can hold only a single class

Comment: applying lapply works but isn't there a generic way to do it? as it is just a sample data and I can't apply it on my original 100k data

Comment: Also isn't it better to take chr instead of factors?

Comment: @melissa  Yes, you can do this on a generic way. `un1 <- sort(unique(unlist(df[1:2])); df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], factor, levels = un1)`

Comment: @melissa Yes, character is better, but if we need all the combinations where the 0 rows also should be kept, then `factor` will preserve it

Answer (score 0):

Use `tidyr::spread` function as follow:

```
require(tidyr)
df %>% spread(key=M_User,value = Total,fill = 0)
```